# which is simple way to create layout android

Tags: android

I want to display For each and every tab different layout so what a easy way to display

1. Create different layout and add or merge in.
2. Create only one layout for different tab and set visiblity to gone and visible.

Which one is easy way or other way please tell me.
Here attached screen: http://screencast.com/t/pEhf8g0b

Comment: `My requirement is...`,stackoverflow is not your developer...

Answer (score 0):

Create XML's for each tab, for example education.xml, activities.xml, and in the onCreate call that layout, for example in Education onCreate() call setContentView(R.layout.education); and for Activities call setContentView(R.layout.activities);